# Protected routes are working in local machine but not accessible in live server

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, cryptojs

I'am building a set of api's that are protected in nodejs. It is accessible only if the user gets a valid JWT token. For security purpose I'am encrypting it using crypto-js from front-end through headers and sending it for decryption and verification of JWT token. It works in local machine but does not work in production server.
Why this happens?
Thank you.

Comment: I think using CORS will help u. try using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors although u should be careful this opens up an access to all IPs

Comment: please check the console for more descriptive error